# Nested parallel program in C++ with OpenMP

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I do not understand that how the operating system solves the nested parallel program as the following for loop parts.

```
omp_set_num_threads(16);
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cblas_dgemv...
}
```

At first, I set the maximum number of threads used in model as 16. I want to unroll the for loop by using `OpenMP` and the `clubs_dgemv` is the Intel Math Kernel Library c interface which is also executed in multithread mode.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking here. What do you mean by "*the operating system solves*"?

Comment: @Qubit The Intel Math Kernel Library can dynamic manage the threads activated by the operating system. And I believe that the operating system can mange the nested multithreading problem in the kernel mode.

Comment: I still have absolutely no idea what you really want to know here. Is it that you want to use 16 threads in total, of which 10 go to the for loop and then only 6 of those loop iterations are allowed to use another thread?

Comment: @Qubit What I want to know is exact the pseudocode code. I want to use the OpenMP to unroll the for loop in parallel mode, however, the cblas_dgemv is also parallel function. This is exact nested problem.

Comment: The Intel MKL pin threads to cores? If not, this code will create a bag of `10xN` MKL threads where `N` is the number of threads that each `gemv` call creates. The OS probably will manage it in the same way that it manages not-pinned OpenMP threads: concurrently on all cores. A mess, once it could create more threads than cores.

Comment: You can force MKL to create more threads than there are cores. Assuming no such manipulation of the runtime is done beforehand here (but nested parallelism is enabled via the relevant call), then OpenMP will create 10 threads, 1 for each value of `i`, after that however I don't know what MKL will do for each of the iterations. I can choose to give the first one the remaining 6 threads and evaluate the other calls sequentially, or something else. Typically I'd suggest setting the number of threads for each iteration manually, to be on the safe side.

Comment: Though I don't see a use for having ome `dgemv` calls run in parallel while the other are sequential if they are all working with the same dimensions, you'll end up waiting for the ones running a single thread, may as well set them all to run ona single thread.

Comment: @Qubit Thank you so much! That is what we want to ask. I just do not know how the mkl deals with this situation.

Comment: @648trindade Actually, I am not sure about that. I just know that the intel CPU can use the Hyper Threading technology which can permit one core execute more than one thread.